# How to fit set of values in logarithm curve?

Tags: curve-fitting, logarithm

I have some set of linear data `1` to `100`.

I want to create weight graph for that data based on `log` value.

Log value ranges are `1` to `0.5` means for linear data point value `1` its `1` and for `100` `logarithm` value is `0.5`

I want to for all data points from `1` to `100`, in logarithm range `1` to `0.5`.

What equation should I use or how can I do that?

Comment: So you are trying to figure out what base gives you a logarithm value for (100) = 0.5     Is that as you see it?   Let's call the base = X   Can you tell me the equation in exponential form?  (hint: I'm not going to do your homework for you...)

Comment: @zipzit I actually want to fit all points 1 to 100 in range of 1 to 0.5 with the logarithm curve. I am not sure finding the base for 100 will help me in this case.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  It's the first step in getting you to where you need to go. It's a simple question. Again, what is the exponential equation involving base X, 100 and 0.5 in exponential form?

Comment: @zipzit its X^0.5=100

Comment: Awesome.  Nice one.  Now solve for X.  Now that you have X (the base for your logarithm) you can calculate the coordinates for plotting your raw data.    One axis will be linear (with a value = 1 to 100) , the other will be logarithm (base X) of each value.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @zipzit Ya it makes sense but with the same base with data value 1 it should give me 1 as output but it is giving me 0. :(

Comment: @zipzit I want to find a base for which datapoint 1 gives me ans 1 and data point 100 gives me ans 0.5

Comment: @zipzit thanks for help. I got the ans. just simply substract all values from 1 is giving me exact what I want . Thanks a lot :)